# How to sync Mongo-express database to google cloud storage bucket?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, mongo-express

Currently, I'm trying to connect Mongo express database collection to gcp and sync up these two. Can anyone please help to connect & sync up Mongodb collection and google cloud storage.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what do you want to achieve? What kind of data are you going to fecth for example? Mongo DB is a database and Cloud Storage is intended to store arbitrary files, images, zips, txt, etc... so what do you want to store in mongo, you want references for those files? you want to get the metadata? also when you mention sync you mean real time sync? onces per day sync?

Comment: I need to do real time sync of jsonl or csv file from Mongodb to google cloud storage.

Comment: in that case is a bit up to you to make this as you will need to implement the logic on your back end to push the data to Cloud Storage or, depending on your environment you could use [cloud storage fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) or [stream data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming). Still, you really should explain what do you want to achieve and some details of your set up if you want any help here

Comment: Actually, I have to sync Mongo-express collection and bigquery. In Mongo db, I have Standalone, not replica set. so, I decided to sync mongodb to gcs(google cloud storage) and connect bigquery using [Bigquery data transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dts-introduction) . This my idea but I'm stuck to sync mongodb collection to gcs. Can you please help me. Thank you in Advance!!!